# I'm trying to run input in my terminal but everytime I go to turn it on I get an error message "Unable to write into user settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

The error reads " Unable to write user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again. So I click Open Settings and the attached picture is the code I get and I have no idea how to fix it. Can someone help me please?

I tried to find out what the error was and all it's telling me is "Expected a JSON object, array or literal.

Comment: there is no attached picture.

Comment: you must have edited the `settings.json` file and made an error, open the `settings.json` file and fix the error. Or delete parts of the file to find the line with the problem if the error message does not tell you, you can try [JSON Validate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-json-validate)